# JavaScript why is map not returning all the indexes?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I dont know but this seems like a bug with javascript or it has to be my machine or something this map is not returning all indexes

```
const words = [];
let array = [
    {
      id:"h2j3x33",
      author:"Zindril",
      body:"Glad to help. Hope it helps you clear even faster next reset!",
      permalink:"zindi.page",
      utc:1624278978,
      replies:""
    },
    {
      id:"33",
      author:"highperson",
      body:"Im a the best!",
      permalink:"thebest.com",
      utc: 054,
      replies: ""
    },
    {
      id:"43",
      author:"charizard",
      body:"fire burn",
      permalink:"dragon.com",
      utc:342342,
      replies: {id: 324, author: "Ash", body: "Skinny", permalink: "pokemon.com", utc: 1, replies: ""}
    }
]
```

```
words.push(array)
console.log(words)
console.log(words.length) // this says the length is 1 so the index will be 0
```

```
let whyOnlyFor1Obj = words.map((word, idx, arr) => word[idx]) // word[idx] only returns the first object if I try forEach i get undefined
console.log(whyOnlyFor1Obj)
```

The funny thing is when I do

```
let whyOnlyFor1Obj = words.map((word, idx, arr) => word[2]) // or word[1] I get the other Objects 
console.log(whyOnlyFor1Obj)
```

Is it me or what is wrong with JS on this?

Comment: `words` contains only a single array, maybe you want to map `words[0]` ..?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. `words` has a single element, the array you push into it. It doesn't *merge* the arrays, you have this: `[ [ { id: firstone, etc }, { id: secondone, etc }, ... ] ]` The code you're writing seems to expect a merged array.

Comment: By `words.push(array)` did you mean `words.push(...array)`?

Comment: I meant to do that an empty array of words I want to push that array of object inside it then map over the new words I see now its array of array of object but get all the objects like in the words.map(word => word.id) all the ids basically

Comment: `(word, idx, arr) => word[idx]` doesn't make any sense. `idx` is an index into `arr` (the nested `words` in your case), not into the `word` (which is the `array` in your case).

Comment: @Mohamed So you just want `words[0].map(word => word.id)`?

Comment: Yess thanks ! thats exactly it cant believe i didnt see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `forEach` you get undefined because you are defining function for each element of the array and since you have an array inside another array, you need to use forEach inside `forEach` just like this.

```
words.forEach(function(val,idx){
    val.forEach((value,index)=>{
    console.log(value.id);
})
```